# BCM2046 Bluetooth not working on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth, broadcom

Having installed Arch, I have now got down to the task of configuring it and getting all the hardware to work. I managed to get my WiFi working, 
but my Bluetooth still does not work. I have followed the instructions on the Bluetooth article on the ArchWiki, 
by installing bluez and bluez-utils,loading the btusb module and starting the Bluetooth service. I got as far as issuing the power on command to `bluetoothctl`.

However, I got the output : `No default controller available`.

lsusb lists the device as:

```
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub 
(part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
```

Any thoughts on how the issue can be fixed?

Comment: Can you try starting `bluetoothctl` with `sudo`: `sudo bluetoothctl`?

Comment: Please edit the question to include full results from terminal for `lsusb`

Comment: Have you installed `bluez-hid2hci` and started the bluetooth service with `systemctl enable bluetooth.service` ?